# Fatal error while printing a 2 dimensional array

Tags: c, arrays, gameboy

Im having this problem with a little chunk of code:

```
for(x = 0; x < 8; x++){
for(y = 0; y < 8; y++){
printf(" %d", occupy[x][y]);
}
printf(" \n");
}
```

I'm making a randomly generated maze game for the Gameboy, and I'm using a 2d array to know where each screen is in the maze. For testing I'm trying to print that array so I can see if its generating properly before I move on. When I try to compile with that little chunk of code I get an error on the top line of it, then says fatal Compiler internal error in file blah blah blah. Is there like a big no-no in that code that I didn't know of?

Full code:

```
#include <gb\gb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <rand.h>


#define UP 0x01U
#define RIGHT 0x02U
#define DOWN 0x04U
#define LEFT 0x08U

int occupy[8][8]= {
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
};


void generate(){
int temp;
int x;
int y;
UBYTE restrict;
UBYTE direction;
for(x = 0; x < 8; x++){
for(y = 0; y < 8; y++){
occupy[x][y] = 0;
}
}
/* ========Occupy=Cleared========== */
restrict = 0x00U;
x = rand() & 7;
y = rand() & 7;

if(x == 6 || x == 7){ restrict += RIGHT;}
if(x == 0 || x == 1){ restrict += LEFT;}
if(y == 0 || y == 1){ restrict += UP;}
if(y == 6 || y == 7){ restrict += DOWN;}

/* in the rest of generation wrap this block in if(restrict != 0x0FU){ */

do{
temp = rand() & 3;
if(temp == 0){ direction = UP;}
if(temp == 1){ direction = RIGHT;}
if(temp == 2){ direction = DOWN;}
if(temp == 3){ direction = LEFT;}
}while(restrict & direction);


occupy[x][y] = 5;
if(direction == UP){ occupy[x][y-1] = 1;}
if(direction == RIGHT){ occupy[x+1][y] = 2;}
if(direction == DOWN){ occupy[x][y+1] = 3;}
if(direction == LEFT){ occupy[x-1][y] = 4;}

for(x = 0; x < 8; x++){
for(y = 0; y < 8; y++){
printf(" %d", occupy[x][y]);
}
printf(" \n");
}

}


void main(){
generate();

}
```

Comment: This code for itself does not compile. How would we know if adding the rest of your code would make a compiler happy?

Comment: Getting something like a "Compiler internal error" is going to be very compiler-specific, you shouldn't *(theoretically)* be causing those as a user.  Please edit your post to provide a *complete* example that someone can paste into an editor and compile to reproduce the error...and also identify what compiler (and version of it) you are using.

Comment: key questions that are not answered in that code snippit: 1) how is 'x' defined 2) how is 'y' defined 3) how is occupy defined  4) which compiler?  With the answers to those questions (and it would also help if the code were indented) we might be able to help

Comment: Often the real cause of an error is shortly before the indicated line... it helps to show the code *around* the reported error too.

Comment: Im using gbdk to compile. Just updated with whole code.

Comment: 'restrict' is a 'C' keyword

Comment: this kind of line: 'x = rand() & 7;' will set 'x' to be in the range 0...6.  definitely not what the next lines of code is expecting.  The line should be: 'x = rand() & 8;'  the same goes for setting 'y'

Comment: the main function is not correctly defined.  it should be: int main() { ...  return(0); }  If all warning were enabled for the compiler, it would have raised a warning about that.

Comment: Thanks for the catch on the 7 rows thing. I tried changing it all the "restrict" to "block", but im still getting the error

Comment: x = rand() and 7 just gives me a random number between 0 - 7. if I did x = rand() & 8 the only number it could give me would be 8 or 0. if you use void for a function you don't need a return.

Comment: Just for your reference, there are several things defined in [GB\GB.H](http://gbdk.sourceforge.net/doc/html/gb.h.html#a0), specifically `J_START`, `J_SELECT`, `J_A`, `J_B`, `J_UP`, `J_DOWN`, `J_LEFT`, and `J_RIGHT`.  Redefining those things is unneeded (though not the cause of your error)  EDIT: Though it appears that that isn't what you are using those numbers for joypad anyways, so this comment is probably useless.

Comment: In any case, this code looks fine.  I've been able to get it to compile by removing the array accessing from the final printf, but it works any other way.  Sigh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This compiles under my version of GBDK fine, although I'm not sure why the changes I make are what fixes it.

Changes made:

- `occupy` is now an array of `unsigned int` rather than just `int` (without this change `sdcc` crashes)
- `printf` call inside of loop was changed from `" %d"` to `" %u"` (as the value is unsigned)
- A `printf` showing the address of `occupy` has been added.  If I remove it or change it to do something else, `sdcc` crashes.  This is silly, but it seems to be required.  I'm looking in to alternatives that don't need a pointless `printf`.

  - Note that the following can be used instead, which results in nothing being printed (as in it tries to write to address `$0000`, but that's read only and fails).  It's still stupid but doesn't display anything.  It might still cause some slowdown though.

    ```c
    sprintf(0, "", &occupy);
    ```
- I also improved indentation.

```c
#include <gb\gb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <rand.h>


#define UP 0x01U
#define RIGHT 0x02U
#define DOWN 0x04U
#define LEFT 0x08U

unsigned int occupy[8][8] = {
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
};

void generate(){
    int temp;
    int x;
    int y;
    UBYTE restrict;
    UBYTE direction;

    for(x = 0; x < 8; x++){
        for(y = 0; y < 8; y++){
            occupy[x][y] = 0;
        }
    }
    /* ========Occupy=Cleared========== */
    restrict = 0x00U;
    x = rand() & 7;
    y = rand() & 7;

    if(x == 6 || x == 7){ restrict += RIGHT;}
    if(x == 0 || x == 1){ restrict += LEFT;}
    if(y == 0 || y == 1){ restrict += UP;}
    if(y == 6 || y == 7){ restrict += DOWN;}

    /* in the rest of generation wrap this block in if(restrict != 0x0FU){ */

    do{
        temp = rand() & 3;
        if(temp == 0){ direction = UP;}
        if(temp == 1){ direction = RIGHT;}
        if(temp == 2){ direction = DOWN;}
        if(temp == 3){ direction = LEFT;}
    }while(restrict & direction);


    occupy[x][y] = 5;
    if(direction == UP){ occupy[x][y-1] = 1;}
    if(direction == RIGHT){ occupy[x+1][y] = 2;}
    if(direction == DOWN){ occupy[x][y+1] = 3;}
    if(direction == LEFT){ occupy[x-1][y] = 4;}

    printf(" %x\n", &occupy); //Strangely without this printf it doesn't compile???
    for(x = 0; x < 8; x++){
        for(y = 0; y < 8; y++){
            printf(" %u", occupy[x][y]);
        }
        printf(" \n");
    }

}


void main(){
    generate();
}
```

Here's a few other comments about the code:

- You don't ever initialize the RNG, so the results will always be the same.  There's a few ways to set the seed.  Normally, you do it with time on the title screen, or you can have a seed chooser.

  ```c
  //Seeds RNG by time taken to press start
  void seedRNG() {
      UINT16 seed = 0;

      printf("Press start\n");
      while (!(joypad() & J_START)) {
          seed++;
      }
      initrand(seed);
  }
  ```

  ```c
  //Seeds RNG with a user-chosen number.
  //Requires inclusion of <gb\console.h>.
  void seedRNG() {
      UINT16 seed = 0x8000U; //In the middle to prevent over/underflow issues

      printf("Seed:");

      while (!(joypad() & J_START)) {
          if (joypad() & J_UP) { seed++; }
          if (joypad() & J_DOWN) { seed--; }
          gotoxy(0,1);
          printf("%x\n", seed);
          delay(10);
      }
      initrand(seed);
  }
  ```
- You don't actually need to print stuff out to view it in this case, since you can use the "Memory Viewer" found in most emulators.  The locations can be found in a RAM map generated with the `-Wl-j` or `-Wl-m` options.
- I recommend using [`INT16`](http://gbdk.sourceforge.net/doc/html/asm_gbz80_types.h.html#a2) or `WORD` rather than `int` and [`UINT16`](http://gbdk.sourceforge.net/doc/html/asm_gbz80_types.h.html#a3) or `UWORD` rather than `unsigned int`, ect, as they include the sizes in their names.  `UBYTE` and such are also nice to use.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was starting to think that the gameboy didn't support 2 dimensional arrays.

Answer (score -1):

```
the following compiles



#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // contains rand and srand function prototypes
#include <time.h>
//#include "gb\gb.h"

void generate( void );

#define UP 0x01U
#define RIGHT 0x02U
#define DOWN 0x04U
#define LEFT 0x08U
typedef unsigned char UBYTE;

int occupy[8][8] =
{
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
};

int main()
{
    generate();
    return(0);
}


void generate()
{
    int temp;
    int x;
    int y;
    UBYTE block;
    UBYTE direction;

    for(x = 0; x < 8; x++)
    {
        for(y = 0; y < 8; y++)
        {
            occupy[x][y] = 0;
        }
    }
    /* ========Occupy=Cleared========== */
    block = 0x00U;
    srand(time(NULL) ); // initialize rand()
    x = rand() & 8;
    y = rand() & 8;

    if(x == 6 || x == 7){ block += RIGHT;}
    if(x == 0 || x == 1){ block += LEFT;}
    if(y == 0 || y == 1){ block += UP;}
    if(y == 6 || y == 7){ block += DOWN;}

    /* in the rest of generation wrap this block in if(block != 0x0FU){ */

    // NOTE:
    // in the following while loop if direction is not the same a block
    // then the loop will immediately exit
    // probably not what you want to do.
    do{
        temp = rand() & 4;
        if(temp == 0){ direction = UP;}
        if(temp == 1){ direction = RIGHT;}
        if(temp == 2){ direction = DOWN;}
        if(temp == 3){ direction = LEFT;}
    } while(block & direction);


    // NOTE:
    // in the following code,
    // 'x' and/or 'y' could be 0 or 7
    // in either case, one or more of the following statements
    // can/will cause accessing outside of the bounds
    // of the occupy[][] array
    occupy[x][y] = 5;
    if(direction == UP)   { occupy[x][y-1] = 1;}
    if(direction == RIGHT){ occupy[x+1][y] = 2;}
    if(direction == DOWN) { occupy[x][y+1] = 3;}
    if(direction == LEFT) { occupy[x-1][y] = 4;}

    for(x = 0; x < 8; x++)
    {
        for(y = 0; y < 8; y++)
        {
            printf(" %d", occupy[x][y]);
        }
        printf(" \n");
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't help me at all. Do you know how bitwise operations work? I had x = rand() & 7, because that does a bitwise and with 7 which is 0111 so that limits it to being between 0000 and 0111 which is 0-7. The do while loop is exactly what I wanted to do so that direction is not blocked. And no it will not access outside the bounds of occupy, because if it picked a spot where it would be, it blocks that direction so it cannot do that. Thanks anyway.